# Need to filter data on condition

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2010

I have sales data. the orders get sales codes, like if the order came from web chat. We are dealing with orders which had sales rep involved, not automatic online order.

Each such order will get a code of 001. then also will get for example
'BCS'

so we would have data as

```
order#   Ord.date  ord.time  Amt etc.  sales code

12345     05/18/15  090000    100.00       001
12345     05/18/15  100000    100.00        BCS
```

so this is fine, the problem I am having in my crystal report is when the enter a 3rd code. The app is not stopping. but so when we have  a 3rd row

```
12345     05/18/15   140000    100.00        BCQ
```

so this 3rd row is throwing off my CR totals.

I need to create a view on this data that will return all 001 and then only the first of a non 001 code, meaning according to the lower date/time. note that is entirely possible for there to be various dates, but we would want the earlier one only.

I am not sure how to make such a condition in SQL Query. So in our example we want the 001 row and the BCS because the time and date is earlier than the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Select * from 
(
    Select *
    , row_number() over (partition by [OrderNo]
                       order by case SalesCode when '001' then 1 else 2 end
                       , Ord.Date, Ord.Time
                       )
                    as RowN
    from MyTable
) a
where a.RowN in (1,2)
```

If the row with `SalesCode` 001 is always the first row created for an order, then you can skip the case statement and just order by Date and time, like this, which will return the first two rows for every Order, by date and time:

```
Select * from 
(
    Select *
    , row_number() over (partition by [OrderNo]
                       order by Ord.Date, Ord.Time
                       )
                    as RowN
    from MyTable
) a
where a.RowN in (1,2)
```

Note that both of these assume that each Order has only one 001 row.  If they could have multiple 001 rows followed by a non-001 row, and you want to return all 001 rows, a different solution will be needed.

Comment: 001 is always the first one,

Comment: @Hassan - did this solution work for you?  If not, please let us know what did not work.